# What is the procedure to add description to a newly created tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

After getting enough reps (I am not sure how much), one can create tags.

Questions:

1. What is the procedure to add small description to the tag?
2. What is the procedure to make synonyms? Eg: EU and European union.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [create tags](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) on this site after reaching 150 reputation. You can do this simply by adding the new tag to a question - it will be created automatically.

To add a description to your tag, you can visit the tag's 'About' page. In your case, you have created the [chinese-communist-party](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese-communist-party) tag, and you can find this tag's information [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/chinese-communist-party/info). Any registered user can suggest edits to this information, and [trusted users](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (4k rep) can have edits approved automatically.

Ideally, a tag should have a tag wiki and usage guidance. Details on what these should contain can be found [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts).

In order to propose synonyms to a tag, users require the '[create tag synonyms](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)' privilege which is granted at 1,250 rep. They also require an answer score of 5 on the tag. These are then voted on by other users with the requisite answer score. You can also make a post on meta to suggest a synonym if you're not sure, or don't have the requirements to propose a tag synonym, after which a mod may implement your suggestion.